How to have italicized double-storey "a"?
The letter a is usually double-storey in Roman and single-storey in italics (and in math code), but I hope to have both $a$ and a italicized double-storey version in math code. 
I don't think there are built-in options for double-storey a in math code, so I'm asking if there's a way to force texts to be slant

I guess you want slanted, rather than italic.
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{slantedletters}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sl}
\SetSymbolFont{slantedletters}{bold}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{sl}
\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{slantedletters}{`a}

\begin{document}

$a+b=c$ (normal)

{\boldmath $a+b=c$} (boldmath)

$\mathnormal{a}+b=c$ (normal math italic)

$\mathbf{a}+b=c$ (normal mathbold)

\end{document}


The above changes a in math mode to always give the two-story version. If you instead want it to be normal by default, you can define a special command.
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsl}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsl}{bold}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{sl}
\newcommand{\dsa}{\mathsl{a}}

\begin{document}

$a+b=c$ (normal)

$\dsa+b=c$ (two-story)

{\boldmath $a+b=c$} (boldmath)

{\boldmath $\dsa+b=c$} (boldmath)

\end{document}



oh! thank you so much!!

@SprinklingMoss I added a second version, check it out.

great! I appreciate it
